# Pretty URLs with Categories and Tags

Tags: categories, tags

How do I create pretty permalinks for a query page that includes results from both categories and tags.

For instance, if the category is Country (America) and the tag name is city (New York), can I have a permalink like wordpressblog.com/america/new-york for a page that shows all posts belonging to Amercia category and NY tag?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually in your .htaccess although I'm not sure how. In the past I have been able to use partially pretty urls by doing

`http://www.mydomain.com/country/america/?city=new_york`

I would imagine it would easy enough to use mod_rewrite to prettify that even further.

UPDATE: Check this out it looks like it will do exactly what you need!

http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: Thank you. This looks like the best approach at this time.